# Matrices multiplying gives wrong results on CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I've written a small piece of code using CUDA to multiply 2 square matrices. Hovewer, it turns out that most of cells are miscalculated. According to the tutorial I've used, everything should go fine.

```
__global__ void gpuMM(int *C, int *A, int *B, int N)
{
    int row = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int col = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        sum += A[row*N+n]*B[n*N+col];

    C[row*N+col] = sum;
}

#define ROW_SIZE 5
#define MATRIX_LENGTH ROW_SIZE*ROW_SIZE
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

void MultiplyMatrixCUDA(int * pResult, int* pFactorA, int*pFactorB)
{
    int size = MATRIX_LENGTH*sizeof(int);
    int *dA,*dB,*dC;
    cudaMalloc(&dA,size);
    cudaMalloc(&dB,size);
    cudaMalloc(&dC,size);
    int K = 100;
    dim3 threadBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 grid(K,K);

    printf("A:\n");
    DrawMatrix(pFactorA);
    printf("\n");

    printf("B:\n");
    DrawMatrix(pFactorB);
    printf("\n");

    // Copy matrices from the host to device
    cudaMemcpy(dA,pFactorA,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dB,pFactorB,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Execute the matrix multiplication kernel
    gpuMM<<<grid,threadBlock>>>(dC,dA,dB,ROW_SIZE);


    // Allocate memory to store the GPU answer on the host
    int *C;
    C = new int[MATRIX_LENGTH];

    // Now copy the GPU result back to CPU
    cudaMemcpy(C,dC,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dA);
    cudaFree(dB);
    cudaFree(dC);

    printf("\nC from CUDA:\n");
    DrawMatrix(C);
    printf("\nC:\n");
    DrawMatrix(MultiplyWithCPU(pResult,pFactorA, pFactorB));  // the code of multiplying function is irrevelant, I'm sure it works fine (double-checked)

}
```

The result shows that matrices multiplied with standard CPU methods is correct, but the CUDA one is wrong:
[image]
[image]

The first row is always correct, but all the other parts are completely random. Sometimes they are negative, sometimes not. Sometimes they are close to real values, sometimes they are COMPLETELY different.

What is my mistake? I don't see where is the fail. The algorithm looks fine, variables seem to be passed correctly, yet something doesn't work.

--- EDIT

All the variables (pResult and both pFactors) are initialized (and later deleted) in other parts of code.

Comment: Where does `pResult` get initialized?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie They are initialized before I call the `MultiplyMatrixCUDA`, in my `main()`. I've edited my question.

Comment: You're working on a 5x5 matrix, but your blocksize is 16x16.  That means that there is a thread trying to work on a non-existent (row,col) = (0,5) in addition to a thread trying to work on the very real (row,col) = (1,0) - but those two items overlap (0*N + 5 = 1*N + 0 = 5).  So you have multiple work items writing to the same element of C, and some of them are accessing invalid parts of memory, giving nonsense results.  In gpuMM, you should test that row < N and col < N.  The first row is correct because no spurious threads are computing on those items.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Thank you, I'll check it as soon as I get to my home computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the number of threads per block is not equal to the number of elements in the output matrix (you're mapping a 5x5 matrix on a 16x16 block) so some threads are accessing/writing invalid memory positions.

The solution is including a double boundary check in order to solve the problem. This will cause some threads to be idle. The kernel should looks like this:

```
__global__ void gpuMM(int *C, int *A, int *B, int N)
{
    int row = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int col = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if( (row < N) && (col < N))
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n){
            sum += A[row*N+n]*B[n*N+col];       
        }
        C[row*N+col] = sum;
    }
}
```

Another solution -more effective, depending on your device, indeed- is launching less threads per block (25 in this case).

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I have been battling this issue for hours.